# Searching for word in file and add to count

Tags: c, file

I am attempting to search for a word in a file and add to a counter variable every time it appears in the text. In my research I have not been able to find a solution that works. This is the code block I am using so far. N is a variable used earlier in the code to store input from the user(the program prints a menu with multiple options, search is the first in the list). I have checked that the file is opened properly but when I try to execute this block I get an error that buffer != nullptr. Does anyone see the issue?

```
if (strcmp(n, "S") == 0) {
            char search_word = NULL;
            printf("What word would you like to search for?");
            scanf("%s", search_word);
            while(fgets(str, sizeof(str), fp)){
                if ((strstr(str, search_word)) != NULL)
                    i++;
            }
            printf("Your word appears %d times.", &i);
        }
```

Comment: That actually compiles? You should be getting  lots of warnings at the very least.

Comment: Inside your `fgets` loop, replace your `if` statement with another loop that does: `char *found = str; while (1) { found = strstr(found,search_word); if (found == NULL) break; ++i; }`

Comment: @CraigEstey found need move to next char, else will dead loop

Comment: use strtok, or pos=0; pos=strstr(pos), so that you can count repeated instances on single line.

Answer (score 3):

You can use fget instead of scanf

You need to loop strstr a line

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char search_word[100];
    printf("What word would you like to search for?");
    gets(search_word);    // change scanf to gets

    char line[1024];
    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
        char* found = line;

        // After getting a line of characters, loop to find search_word and
        // go to found empty
        while ((found = strstr(found, search_word)) != NULL) {
            i++;
            found++;    // move found to next char
        }
    }

    printf("Your word appears %d times.", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Only incrementing found by 1 brings up interesting question about whether poster intends to count overlapping words... does OP intend that found+=strlen(search_word) (which is constant, so only grab that length once, prior to loop. For example, search for "aaa", and file contains "...aaaaaaaaa..." - how many "aaa"s appear in the above?

Comment: @ChuckCottrill This depends on the author's needs.

Answer (score 1):

First thing i can see as a potential problem is the variable used in the scanf, you're trying to put an array of char in a char, so instead of using `char search_word`, use something like  `char search_word[32];`  this way you're able to read an array of char in this case up to 32 characters. and also another problem you have is the usage of the strstr, the function returns the first time the word is found in a string, meaning that if you are using a string like  `"Hello my name is Jeff. is ..."`and you are using the `strstr` function to search the word `"is"` the return of the function is the a pointer to `"is Jeff. is ..."` so you need to use to return value until you get a null return and then move to the next line.

Comment: Good catch on type of "search_word". The more interesting question is where does scanf put the scanned values? because scanf is interpreting search_word as a char*. As the OP to printf("search_word %p\n",(char*)search_word);